# Why my iPhone app was rejected?

Tags: ios, iphone, xcode, app-store

Here is the message that appears in iTunes Connect Resolution Center:

> Reasons
>
> 3.5: Small and large app icons should be similar, so as to not to cause confusion
>   3.5
>
> We found that the app icon displayed on the device does not
>   sufficiently match the large icon displayed on the App Store, which
>   does not comply with the App Store Review Guidelines.
>
> In your case, the app icon displayed on the device is blank.
>
> < More explanation...>

So, to my understanding the app was rejected because the app icon is blank on the device, but when I install the app on my iPhone 5 via Ad Hoc distribution (which is the closest to App Store distribution) everything looks fine.

Following is the assets App Icon configuration in XCode. Is it looks fine?

[image]

Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: what is your 1024*1024 icon is diff or what with your App icon? might be that is an issue your large icon is different then you app small icons

Comment: Check you all the icon for project.... Now these are 120*120, 152*152, 76*76 these all are same or not

Comment: They don't say that the app icon is blank when you install the app. Look at the icon you put for iTunes on iTunesConnect and the icon on the device, they should be similar.

Comment: The exact same icon of 1024x1024 is on iTunes Connect.

Comment: Also check your target plist for any defined icons under: `Icon file`, `Icon files` and `CFBundleIconFiles*`.

Comment: I have two entries: 'Icon files (IOS 5)', and 'CFBundleIcons~ipad' in the plist file. Both entires contain 0 items. Can this be the reason?

Comment: You still need to add iPad icons because even if it's an iPhone only app, people can still run it on an iPad.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

I found the reason why my app was rejected and I just wish to share the solution for anyone that will face the same issue.

It appears that my app was rejected since the app icon was blank on iPad devices. (Note that iPad devices are still being used by the Apple App Review team testers even though my app is an iPhone only app)

I recently started using images.xcassets for managing my app icon and loading page images. I therefore removed all related files from my app resources but the target plist file had some leftovers that eventually found as the cause to the blank icon on the iPad...

Once I removed an entry called "CFBundleIcons~ipad" from the plist file, the issue was fixed.

Thank you @Leijonien for you comment that helped me to resolve this issue!

Answer (score 0):

You not meet App Icon Requirements

Create different sizes of the app icon for different devices. If you’re creating a universal app, you need to supply app icons in all four sizes.

For iPhone and iPod touch, both of these sizes are required:

120 x 120 pixels
60 x 60 pixels (standard resolution)
For iPad, both of these sizes are required:

152 x 152
76 x 76 pixels (standard resolution)

Referenced by Apple inc for more information visit [Apple icon guidelines](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/userexperience/conceptual/mobilehig/AppIcons.html)